# Scraping and modifying an outout

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to retrieve data from this website with `scraping`:

https://dolar.wilkinsonpc.com.co/dolar-historico/dolar-historico-2018.html

My parser right now looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class HDolarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'historico-dolar'
    allowed_domains = ['dolar.wilkinsonpc.com.co']
    start_urls = ['https://dolar.wilkinsonpc.com.co/dolar-historico/dolar-historico-2018.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="tabla_dh"]'):
            date = sel.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]').extract()
            location = sel.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[2]').extract()
            print(date, location)
```

The output looks like:

`['<div class="dh_col_fecha">16 Septiembre 2018</div>'] ['<div class="dh_col_precio"><b>$ 3,026.05</b></div>']`

And I need like this:

**16 Septiembre 2018;3026.05**

I was trying to replace with w3lib and others without success. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try the beautifulsoup module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use/modify this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class HDolarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'historico-dolar'
    allowed_domains = ['dolar.wilkinsonpc.com.co']
    start_urls = ['https://dolar.wilkinsonpc.com.co/dolar-historico/dolar-historico-2018.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Select all div containing a div with a class whose name contains the phrase "dh_cal_fecha"
        for subject in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabla_dh"]/div[./div[contains(@class, "dh_col_fecha")]]'):
            yield {
                'date': subject.xpath('./div[@class="dh_col_fecha"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'location': subject.xpath('./div[@class="dh_col_precio"]//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

If you run this code with:

> scrapy runspider HDolarSpider.py -o Report.json

You will generate a report in JSON format with the structure as in the example below:

[image]

Total 262 items.